# ModSecurity - error parsing actions unknown action \\

Tags: apache, mod-security

I'm trying to implement OWASP CRS 3.0.0-rc1 on ModSecurity 2.9.1  (Apache\Ubuntu)

When starting Apache, I'm getting the following error.

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 35 of /etc/apache2/conf/crs/rules/RESPONSE-50-DATA-LEAKAGES-PHP.conf:
Error parsing actions: Unknown action: \\
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

This is the snippet from the ruleset

**RESPONSE-50-DATA-LEAKAGES-PHP.conf:**

```
SecRule RESPONSE_BODY "@pmf php-errors.data" \
    "msg:'PHP Information Leakage',\
    id:'950180',\
    phase:response,\
    ver:'OWASP_CRS/3.0.0',\
    rev:'3',\
    maturity:'9',\
    accuracy:'9',\
    t:none,\
    capture,\
    ctl:auditLogParts=+E,\   THIS IS LINE 35
    block,\
```

For some reason, if I simply move line 35 up one...

```
        capture,ctl:auditLogParts=+E,\
```

It no longer squawks about this file... But I get another error

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 31 of /etc/apache2/conf/crs/rules/RESPONSE-50-DATA-LEAKAGES.conf:
Error parsing actions: Unknown action: \\
```

**RESPONSE-50-DATA-LEAKAGES.conf:**

```
SecRule RESPONSE_BODY "(?:<(?:TITLE>Index of.*?<H|title>Index of.*?<h)1>Index of|>\[To Parent Directory\]<\/[Aa]><br>)" \
    "phase:response,\
    rev:'2',\
    ver:'OWASP_CRS/3.0.0',\
    maturity:'9',\
    accuracy:'9',\
    t:none,\       THIS IS LINE 31
    capture,\
```

which again is solved by combining with the line above it.

```
accuracy:'9',t:none,\
```

The odd thing, is that it's NOT the same contents...

I'm just trying to get a handle on what is really causing this error.  And would it be a bug in ModSecurity 2.9.1 or rather the RuleSet itself?  Or something with how the multi line character is parsed?

Comment: Not seeing this. Very odd. What version of Apache are you running? CRS 3 is still work in progress and is actively being discussed on mailing list so may be better asking there: https://lists.owasp.org/mailman/listinfo/owasp-modsecurity-core-rule-set or perhaps here: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/issues/343

Comment: @BazzaDP Apache 2.4.7.  I'll try a few more things and also reach out to the links you left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known apache bug; fixed in 2.4.11.

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55910

Comment: I know this isn't the right place to ask... But think we'll ever see 2.4.11 in Ubuntu 14.04 as a package update?